# Python backtrace from C++ embedded in Python

Tags: python

I have a Python application that has embedded C++.  When running this, the C++ code has a segfault.  The backtrace gives me a bunch of Python interpreter calls - for example , PyEval_EvalFrame.  Is there a way to get the actual Python backtrace?

Comment: paste the codes along with a tutorial on how to do this. :)